# How to inject managed bean into FacesContext?

Tags: java, jsf, jsfunit

How can I replace an `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean with my own copy of it in `FacesContext`? All I have is an instance of `FacesContext` (I'm inside JSFUnit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application scoped beans are stored in the [application map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getApplicationMap%28%29) with the managed bean name as key.

So, this should do:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getApplicationMap().put("managedBeanName", new Bean());
```

By the way, deeper under the JSF covers up to the Servlet API, the application map is just a mapping of [`ServletContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) attributes. Useful to know when it happens that you've only the `ServletContext` at your hands. And in the same line, the [session map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29) maps to `HttpSession` attributes and the [request map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestMap%28%29) to `HttpServletRequest` attributes. Use them for session and request scoped beans respectively.

Comment: BalusC you once posted about using attributes / info across redirects. You suggested using the sessionmap and afterwards clearing it with a filter. I think a link to the post might be helpful for some (i really can no longer find that one, you are posting too much §|¦¬). Or at least it seems a lot nicer to clean the HttpSession and fill the request map instead of doing the FacesContext.getCurrentInstance....

Comment: This one maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610771/dynamic-chart-generation-pass-object-to-servlet-from-jsf-1-2 Anyway, the real right solution depends on JSF version and functional requirement.